# How to create a array of consecutive numbers array in numpy?

Tags: arrays, numpy, stack

I'm looking to generate an array as follows:

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

Here is how I generate in NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1, 10)
b = np.arange(2, 11)
np.stack((a, b), axis=1)
```

Is there any function in NumPy that does this directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest answer I can think of, using [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) black magic:

```
# Solution 1:
np.r_[:9][:,None]+[1,2]
# Solution 2:
np.r_['c',:9]+[1,2]
```

Or also using [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) but without broadcasting this time:

```
# Solution 3:
np.r_['1,2,0', :10, 1:11]
```

Every solution produce, as expected:

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

Comment: Now, that is just impressive.  Simple but impressive. +1

Comment: I feel bad about my answer now! Thank you for showing us `np.r_`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any built-in to do this kind of arrangement, but here are some alternative solutions.

- Using a half step size and [`np.floor`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html):

  ```
  >>> np.floor(np.arange(1.5, 10.5, .5)).reshape(9, 2)
  ```
- Using [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

  ```
  >>> np.repeat(np.arange(1, 11), 2)[1:-1].reshape(9, 2)
  ```
- Using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) (imo the best method):

  ```
  >>> as_strided(np.arange(1, 11), shape=(9, 2), strides=(8, 8))
  ```

  Since the 2D->1D mapping you're looking to achieve is `i + j = k`, strides must be `(1, 1)` in bytes *i.e.* `(8, 8)` in bits.